# Copy/Edit Textfile and Save in Original Encoding

Tags: c#, text, encoding, io, save

I am trying to open a large number of text-based files (php, css, js, html, tmpl, etc.) and perform operations on their content before re-saving them at a different place (mirrored).

Background: the whole thing is a tool which web-developers can use to automagically perform certain clean-up procedures on their projects before releasing them.

However, currently, this only supports UTF8 and re-saves EVERYTHING as UTF8. I have created a load of text-files in different encodings: ANSI, Korean, UTF8, etc.

However, everything gets re-saved as UTF8 and, in certain instances, loses characters (such as Korean, Cyrillic, Chinese, etc.).

What I aim to do is open the file in it's ORIGINAL encoding, then do my operations and save it in the exact same encoding it was previously.

Below, you can see my current attempt which yields undesired results.

```
var cfi = new FileInfo("myfile.ext");
System.IO.TextReader tr = cfi.OpenText();
string fileContent = tr.ReadToEnd();
tr.Close();

// Do stuff to fileContent

File.WriteAllText(cfi.FullName, fileContent);
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your problem is, that text files does not explicitly state their encoding. Therefore you need to know the encoding beforehand to get this right. If you don't know it, you can only guess, based on the content of the file. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html (The exception is UTF-8 with a BOM, in this case you can detect the encoding accurately).

Comment: In other words, your best bet is a guess. There is no reliable way of doing this - for instance, Notepad/Windows has a guessing algorithm that is sometimes wrong: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx

Comment: Hello driis, thank you for your comment - that's a shame! All I wish to do is to open the file, delete certain strings, and save it in its original encoding somewhere else. So, this is definitely not possible? Many thanks for your help (the link is also super-helpful).

Comment: I am not quite sure if I worded the question correctly. For example, I can open any textfile with Notepad++, delete some stuff and then save it as is. Surely, this can be done programmatically in C#? :-)